# Strange light artifacts on flat glossy objects in eevee

Tags: shaders, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting

For some reason, when using a glossy material (and I've tried many values of roughness but the problem is still there) on any object, even the basic plane, the lighting looks like this, with this strange glitchy thing at the center, by moving the light source and/or the object the problem persists and this glitchy pattern actually continues, I've tried creating a new file and recreating the material, the plane and the light source, in that case the problem doesn't appear. What could be causing this problem?

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your object? (upload and share the URL it will generate) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here it is https://pasteall.org/blend/2996e0a8d2bd4c6d9a3e20ec419a1691

Comment: Would this happen to be on an AMD GPU?

Comment: so for those who will look at your file it happens if we are in top view / normal (and non orthographic)

Comment: No, I have a 1070, btw yes it doesn't appear in an orthographic view

Comment: I'm not sure where it comes from, maybe it's a bug   :/